# Universal (MacOS and iOS) iCloud path to file?

Tags: icloud

Is there a way to get a universal path to a file in the iCloud directory? That is, a way to copy a path to a file stored in iCloud which will correctly direct to the file whether you use the path on iOS or MacOS?

Specifically, I'd like to link to an iCloud file in my Bear note taking app. However, I want this link to correctly function whether I use it from my Mac or from my iOS devices. Is there a way I can get such a link?

**Edit:**
Ideally, a solution which also works offline would be best. For example, on the Mac, a link such as `file:///Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~Preview/Documents/my_file.pdf` will reveal the linked file. However, this doesn't work on iOS. An equivalent link which works both on iOS and MacOS would be the ideal case. The first solution provided works as a device agnostic link, however, it does require an internet connection.

Comment: I wasn't aware that iCloud file links are device specific and thought they were all universal.  Have you verified they're specific?

Comment: @fsb, by file links, I was attempting to use something like: `file:///Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~Preview/Documents/my_file.pdf`. Such a link works on Mac, but does not work on iOS.

Comment: That's true because iOS doesn't have such a file system.  The easiest way to access files stored in iCloud is to use the Apple-provided links indicated in the @sam's answer.  Your question doesn't mention that you want it to work offline, also.  If you update your question you might get answers that meet your criteria.

Comment: @fsb, thank you. When I had originally written the question, I was in the mindset of a `file:///` type link, so I hadn't even considered there might be a solution which would require an internet connection. I was only thinking about a local reference URL. Of course, this was a bit of a silly mindset given the question is about a cloud storage service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will do exactly what you want, but here's how to get a link to a file stored in iCloud:

**On your Mac:**

1. In Finder, open your iCloud Drive (found in the Go menu or `Shift`+`Command`+`I`)
2. Right click on the file and choose *Share* > *Show People*
3. Expand *Share Options* and adjust permissions as needed
4. Click *Copy Link*

**On your iPhone/iPad:**

1. Go to the *Files* app
2. Tap the file to open it
3. Tap the share icon (bottom left)
4. Tap *Add People*
5. Adjust *Share Options* as needed
6. Tap *Copy Link*

**On the web:**

1. Go to [*Drive* on *iCloud*](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/)
2. Click to highlight the file
3. Click the *Add People* icon in the top menu bar
4. Click *Copy Link*
5. Adjust permissions and click *Share*
6. The shareable URL will shown

Comment: This almost does everything it should. The one piece that's missing is that it requires internet to work. Something like a `file:///` link will work even if there is no internet (and the file was a recent file and so still downloaded). However, this fulfills most of what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you can use this, for example:

`"/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/"`